# Predicting instantaneous ECG Signal

Tags: prediction, biostatistics, curve-fitting, signal-processing

I have an ECG signal and want to predict the nth instance of signal based on previous m samples.

Which of these (or some other) solution will be best suitable for it:

1. Using past m samples as features and (m+1)th as the *y*
2. Using Signal Modelling algorithms (like ***Padé approximant or Levinson-Durbon Recursion***)

If using Signal Modelling algorithms, which algorithm (and order of poles) will be most suitable to ECG as it can vary quickly. Thanks!

Comment: Is 'ECG' referring to electrocardiographs or something else?

Comment: @IWS Yes Electrocardiographs